# Test strategy advice - need to record verified results of running a method and use them for testing purposes

Tags: c#, testing

I'm new to testing and I need an advice for the best testing strategy (and its application).
Here's my problem:

I have a program that reads a file and automatically extracts its structure. I want to test the method that makes this "intelligent" extraction. Initially I can use a few files to check if the method is doing the correct extraction. Then I want to use these files and the (correct) extraction results for testing purposes. As the extraction results have been verified they should (and must) be used for further tests.

So, I have something like: *for "this particular file" I expect "this result".*

The problems:

1. It's easy to get the input files for the test. I will store them in a specific directory. What about the results? They affect the contents of the object that stores the file structure. In this case I may need to save this object in a file as well. With serialization I'm afraid that with object's structure changes, it will be difficult to reuse the previous saved objects.
2. With more and more results I may have hundreds of files and results and the test will take a lot of time. I expect that testing time will not be a big issue.

I need testing because my "extraction algorithm" used in the method will change often. I can't cope with all possibilities in order to have a perfect extraction algorithm. So, my solution is to build an initial algorithm that works in a dozen files and each time that I find a failure in the algorithm for a particular file I change the algorithm in order to solve the problem with that file. This change should be tested in order the previous files and results are still valid.

Any suggestion for the testing strategy?

Comment: What type is your output? Is it a `c#` object?

Comment: Yes, It's a C# object. It is not a simple object in the sense that involves directly and undirectly objects from several different classes and may be hard to serialize.

Answer (score 1):

For tests you need somewhere a place where you can inject input test data and some place where you can observe some behavior or output.

On the input side: Are files really the only possibility to inject input test data? If yes, the application does not have a good testable design. Tests with files are hard to maintain. On the output side: The application does not seem to offer a possibility to observe behavior or output. This is points to a design which is not testable.

Even if you find a way to observe behavior our output, there will be only end-to-end tests for all the extraction algorithms. Such end-to-end tests are brittle and a maintenance nightmare. The cause is a not good testable design.

You will be not able to implement a good test strategy without a good testable design. You will need to change the design of your application. On the other hand you may argue that you do not want to change the design without any tests in place. It seems to be a chicken-and-egg problem.

How to get out of such a situation? A combination of test and refactoring strategies might help. On a high-level this might work like this:

1. Build a few representative end-to-end tests. Therefore even use the
   serialization trick. This is just to verify that your program works
   like before you start refactoring. They act as *migration tests*.
2. Refactor you program. Give it places to inject and observe. Such
   places are known as *seams*.
3. As a result you will have testable chunks, which you can put into a
   *test harness*.
4. You refactor and put new seams into the code, to test smaller
   chunks, until you get to the point that you have *unit tests* in
   place. Ideally you will have all your algorithms encapsulated into a family of classes which are all unit tested.

Sounds like a hard job? No, in reality it is even harder than it sounds. Refactoring an application to a testable design needs a lot of experience. Luckily there is a guy who wrote a book about this: [Michael Feather’s 'Working Effectively with Legacy Code'](http://books.google.at/books/about/Working_effectively_with_legacy_code.html?id=CQlRAAAAMAAJ&redir_esc=y).

If you really, really want to implement a good test strategy for the existing application, then read that book. If you want to know what you can do better next time, read that book. If you think that unit testing might be the key to avoid not testable design then start learning about unit tests now. There are a lot of resources in the internet and books about unit testing.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem, you need to persist the results of a test for a later inspection or additional testing.
It has often been reluctant to invest too much time in writing test code, but in this case I see no alternative immediately available.

My advice is to decouple as much as possible the parts involved: the algorithm, the persistence layer (serialization/deserialization), its product and the verification code.

It is possible also that later algorithms implementations can share the same interface, e.g.:

```
interface IMyAlgorithm {
  AbstractOutput DoSomething (InputData);
}

class ConcreteOutput : AbstractOutput {
  // Output for version XXX of your algorithm
}

class XXXAlgorithm {
  ConcreteOutput DoSomething (InputData inputData)
    // Version XXX of you alogorithm
  }
}

interface IPersistenceManager {
  Serialize(AbstractOutput output, string filename);
  AbstractOutput Deserialize(string filename)
}

class XXXPersistenceManager : IPersistenceManager {
  // Handle persistence for XXX hierarchy
}

class XXXTestFixture {
  void BuildObjectWithXXXAlgorithm() {
    IMyAlgorithm XXX = new XXXAlgorithm();
    // run XXX here
    AbstractOutput objXXX = XXX.DoSomething(new InputData());
    IPersistenceManager pmXXX = new XXXPersistenceManager();
    pmXXX.Serialize(objXXX);
  }

  void VerifyThatXXXWorkAsExpected() {
    IPersistenceManager pmXXX = new XXXPersistenceManager();
    AbstractOutput objXXX = pmXXX.Deserialize(path);
    // check object here
  }
}
```

So when you need to create a new algorithm, say YYY, you create the corresponding hierarchy.  Anyway I don't know details and this is just a draft of pseudocode, placed here only to put emphasis on loosely coupling application components.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [approvaltests](http://approvaltests.sourceforge.net/) to verify that 
a given input file always generates the same in memory-object-graph.

To do this you need code that converts the in-memory-object-graph into a string representation of it (i.e overwriting ToString() or having an xml-serializer)

approvaltests verifies that the generated string is always the same.

if the string representation chages you will get a diff-viewer and you are asked to verify if the changes are still ok or not. If the changes are ok you will take this result for later verifications.